# UITable UITextField not displaying data correctly SWIFT 3.0

Tags: swift

My application code is pretty lengthly so I would like to try and get this problem resolved without having to show a bunch of code....but here is what is going on..

I have a tableview with dynamic cells all set up just fine.  There is a textfield in the cell.  When data is entered into the textfield, it is then sent to a label within that same cell.  This happen when a "done" button is pressed.  This all works just find until I have about 6 rows added to the table.  At that point, when the "done" button is pressed, the data gets all mixed up.  Sometimes the data is sent to the wrong cell label and other times it doesn't send at all.  This only happens when I get to about 6 rows.  I am very confused.  The cells are displayed based on a Core Data entity.count...the textfield has the delegate set as itself....I have no clue what could be causing this...only after 6 rows!?

Thank you in advance for your help...like I said, I would like to try and avoid pasting my code here but if I have to provide some I will or I can talk you through what is going on in my code...

***EDIT***

Here is some of my code in cellForRowAt that deals with the textFields in the cell content

```
if searchResults.count > 1 {
        if showInGrams {
            if foods[indexPath.row].units != "g" && foods[indexPath.row].units != "grams" && foods[indexPath.row].units != "Grams" {
                if cell.changeServingTextField.text == "" {
                    cell.labelServing.text = String(format: "%0.2f", (100 / foods[indexPath.row].coefficient) * searchResults[indexPath.row].doubleValue)
                    cell.labelUOM.text = "grams"
                } else {
                    if cell.changeServingSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
                        cell.labelServing.text = String(format: "%0.2f", Double(cell.changeServingTextField.text!)!)
                        cell.labelUOM.text = cell.changeServingSegmentedControl.titleForSegment(at: 0)
                        //show default values
                    } else {
                        cell.labelServing.text = String(format: "%0.2f", Double(cell.changeServingTextField.text!)!)
                        cell.labelUOM.text = cell.changeServingSegmentedControl.titleForSegment(at: 1)
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if cell.changeServingTextField.text == "" {
                    cell.labelServing.text = String(format: "%0.2f", searchResults[indexPath.row].doubleValue * foods[indexPath.row].serving)
                    cell.labelUOM.text = "grams"
                }
            }
        } else {
            if cell.changeServingTextField.text == "" {
                cell.labelServing.text = String(format: "%0.2f", searchResults[indexPath.row].doubleValue * foods[indexPath.row].serving)
                cell.labelUOM.text = foods[indexPath.row].units
            } else {
                if cell.changeServingSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
                    cell.labelServing.text = String(format: "%0.2f", Double(cell.changeServingTextField.text!)!)
                    cell.labelUOM.text = cell.changeServingSegmentedControl.titleForSegment(at: 0)
                } else {
                    cell.labelServing.text = String(format: "%0.2f", Double(cell.changeServingTextField.text!)!)
                    cell.labelUOM.text = cell.changeServingSegmentedControl.titleForSegment(at: 1)

                }
            }
        }
```

I hope this helps, thank you

Comment: It sounds as if you're trying to use cells for data storage and getting caught by the fact that they are cached and reused.  In general, it's safer to never do anything to a cell's contents outside the "cellForRow..." method and configure it **completely** from saved data inside that method.

Comment: Please post code that's pertinent to the issue. Figuring out the minimum amount of code for which your problem is occurring may also help you hone in on the root cause. Remove any properties that don't relate to the issue at hand. Keep going until you have the bare minimum of code that shows the problem. You might find it useful to create a new temporary project of your own for investigating this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  All my code is basically inside the method cellForRow...it is important to use these textFields inside the cell because a lot happens depending on whether they are left blank or not...

Comment: In that case, you at least need to supply the code related to updating the labels...where it happens, how it gets the values to use, and how **those** are updated/stored.

Comment: I edited my post with some code, I hope it helps

Comment: Right...that's what I meant by using cells for data storage.  The moment you start doing `if cell.whatever...` it has the opportunity to break.  (I see that @matt has an answer below, so I'll leave it to him.  :) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is a symptom of `UITableView`'s reuse strategy. May be what you want to do is store the information entered in your `UITextField` in a collection and then every time the `tableView` "reloads", you pick it out from that collection for the current `indexPath` and load it.

Comment: That could work.  How would I put data into some sort of collection based on the indexPath and still be able to load it to the right cell for use?

Comment: Perfect.  I was able to store key value pairs in a dictionary based on the indexPath of the textField I was entering information into.  I retrieve it but calling an if statement on the indexPath using a little String trickery...no more problems.  thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1):

A line like this is never going to work:

```
if cell.changeServingTextField.text == ""
```

The problem is that cells are *reused*. Thus, in its previous life, if the text field had text, it still has text and the test will fail.

Instead, your logic needs to be based entirely on what row this is and what the data corresponding to that row is. And it needs to cover every case, because the cell can be reused.

Answer (score 0):

Things would be clearer if you moved most of this logic into the cells themselves. You can start off by making all your cell's `IBOutlet`s `fileprivate` and assigning a model object or dictionary as a property of the cell. That way you're separating the logic for creating the cells from their display - and will prevent you using cell's outlets to determine state.

While this might not solve your problem directly, separating the logic might clarify where to look.